# H2O Steam uses tmp directory to store deployments

Tags: h2o

I'm currently using H2O steam version 1.1.6 to deploy model endpoints which is working great!
However, steam uses the `/tmp` directory to store these deploys, which is actually only meant for temporary files. Because the `/tmp` has been cleared on my server, I've lost some deploys.

Is there a way to change where these files are stored?

Additionally it's also not possible to delete the deployments through the steam UI because the files are gone, is there a way to delete these as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong; the deployments can be found in `steam/var/master/model`

The files and directories that are located in `/tmp` are created by jetty.